# 500 Internal Server Error when using contactGroups.members.modify to add label to new person with People API

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-people-api

So I am creating a new contact and trying to add a new label to it on the sequence but I keep getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

```
        PeopleService peopleService = service.getPeopleService();

        Person new_person = new Person();

        List names = new ArrayList<>();
        names.add(new Name().setGivenName(name));
        new_person.setNames(names);

        Person created = peopleService.people().createContact(new_person).execute();
        String id = created.getResourceName();

        List people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(id);
        ModifyContactGroupMembersRequest request = new ModifyContactGroupMembersRequest().setResourceNamesToAdd(people);

        peopleService.contactGroups().members().modify("contactGroups/newsletter", request).execute();
```

Comment: This error is on the server's side, so there is not so much you can do. Try to contact [G Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Comment: Well, that's sad. I opened a new bug for them, let's hope they answer soon.